Define a dot(a,b) function + properties and simplify / expand
I would like to define a  function + rules, and let sympy use the rule for simplification:
a,b,c = symbols("a b c")
dot = function("dot")
rule1 = Eq( dot(a+b,c) , dot(a,c)+dot(b,c))
rule2 = Eq( dot(a,b) , dot(b,a) )

Now, use the above to expand and simplify expressions.
How can this be done? Are there alternatives to sympy that can do this?

from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import x, y

def dot(a,b):
    A, B = ordered((a, b))
    if A != a:
        return dot(b, a)
    if b.is_Add and not a.is_Add:
        a, b = b, a
    if a.is_Add:
        a0, a1 = list(ordered(a.as_two_terms()))
        return dot(a0, b) + dot(a1, b)
    return Function('dot')(a, b)

For example:
>>> dot(y,x)
dot(x, y)
>>> dot(x+1,y)
dot(1, y) + dot(x, y)
>>> dot(x+1,y+2)
dot(1, 2) + dot(1, y) + dot(2, x) + dot(x, y)

But really, all you are doing is returning the canonically ordered Cartesian product of the terms:
def dot2(a,b):
    from sympy.utilities.iterables import cartes
    pairs = cartes(Add.make_args(a), Add.make_args(b))
    return sum(Function('dot')(*ordered(p)) for p in pairs)


Very interesting. Thanks!
This is actually a very impressive implementation of converting the term to canonical representation, using the rules explicitly in code. I'll definitely need to learn this deeper..
I wonder is it possible to do the normalization only when requested - e.g. during expand, and also be able to collect terms back to simplify.

Another way of thinking about this: it's just the product of two polynomials with each term being wrapped in dot. So to go backwards, perhaps, would just be a matter of factoring the (expanded) resultant polynomial.

Yes, that makes sense. I see there is a section in the manual about functions https://docs.sympy.org/latest/guides/custom-functions.html#custom-functions-function-subclass, I'll try to combine that with your answer and post here if it works.

Here is a partial answer, base on the answer of smichr above.
This code adds some formatting and exports negativity. It is usable for my limited case but there are more things that can be done to make it more complete.
This is not as automatic and I hoped, but it does show the sympy concept, so it is worth publishing.
To anyone interested in defining a functions and related assumptions and behaviors, I would recommend reading custom-functions
class dot(Function):
    @staticmethod
    def _export_minus(a, b):
        #should export scalar multiplication.
        sign = 1
        if isinstance(a, Mul) and a.args[0] == -1:
            a = -a
            sign = -1
        if isinstance(b, Mul) and b.args[0] == -1:
            b = -b
            sign = -sign
        if sign == 1:
            return dot(a,b)
        else:
            return -dot(a,b) 
       
    def _eval_expand_basic(self, **hints):
        a, b = self.args
        from sympy.utilities.iterables import cartes
        pairs = cartes(Add.make_args(a), Add.make_args(b))
        return sum(self._export_minus(*ordered(p)) for p in pairs)

    def _latex(self, printer):
        a, b = self.args
        _a, _b = printer._print(a), printer._print(b)
        if(a.is_Add):
            _a = fr'\left( {_a} \right)'
        if(b.is_Add):
            _b = fr'\left( {_b} \right)'
        return fr'{_a} \cdot {_b}'

display(dot(b-c,a))

display(dot(b-c,a).expand())

